# Travelify CSS - Add image directly below nav bar and border / image questions?

Tags: css, image, navigation, border, footer

I am using the travelify theme to build my website and for the most part I am really happy.

How would I add the lace image below the navigation bar as seen in the image? I can do it in firebug but have no idea how this would work with travelify and css.

```
http://test.modellicreations.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/laceundernav.jpg
```

Also, how would I replace the footer dashed border line with an image?

Lastly, how do I put a border/outline around the entire table? Every code I have tried puts a border around every cell which I do not want.

You can see the site here:

[[1](http://test.modellicreations.com): http://test.modellicreations.com](http://test.modellicreations.com)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "The travelify theme" What theme? For what? Are you using WordPress? Or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please put some code directly into your question so we can view your code, see your issue, and help out if we can.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image with css, add this class in your css file style.css :

```
nav#main-nav:after {
content: '';
background: url('http://test.modellicreations.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/lacebarflip.jpg') no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 22px;
visibility: visible;
}

  #main-nav {
background: #006666;
border-color: #006666;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: @TylerH - Travelify is a pretty sweet theme for Wordpress / Woocommerce. I should mention that I am also using a child theme.

Comment: @leftside - Thank you! I am not exactly sure what code I should be giving you since I am using a (wordpress / woocommerce) child theme. I can see code when I use firebug, but other than that, my only pages are a custom css and a functions.php

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! I would give you a big hug if I could! Any chance you know how I can add a solid border around the entire table and change the footer dashed line to an image?

Comment: You can add a solid border to a table with style check this link for example :
http://jsfiddle.net/mtbccpzt/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can replace footer dashed border to an image with this style :

```
#site-generator:before {
background: url('http://test.modellicreations.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/lacetop.jpg') no-repeat;
content: '';
height: 20px;
display: block;
position: relative;
bottom: 20px;
}
```